# Are corporate doctors sinful?

Tags: practical-islam, business, medical

In today's capitalistic world, many professionals work in a corporate setting where the bottom line is to make more profit for the shareholders.

In the medical field, we have many corporate hospitals and the doctors working for them are being forced to write unnecessary medical tests or even admit the patient for at least a few hours or one day to help the hospital rake in more money.

If the doctor or nurse protest, they are told that they are dispensable  and can be fired from the job if they don't fall in line.

Unfortunately this trend is being witnessed not only in the west but over the last decade even in Asia & Africa.

Opening one's own clinic to avoid this practice is also prohibitively expensive these days.

How does a Muslim doctor stay true to his/her religion and profession while trying to earn a meal for his family and pay off their loans?

Will they sinful for toeing the corporate line and fleecing the patients ?

Comment: Very interesting question. Under these circumstances a Muslim must aim at a more fundamental level. What about finding like-minded conscientious doctors to found an honest clinic? This could be a tough job though as it may provoke corporations to sabotage your work. But it would be a noble jihad anyway and jihad always involves hardships but the Divine reward and support would be also significant.